# Optimizing primary id relation table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

tag_relation table has tag_id and comment_id fields *only* and both of them are indexed. (there is no primary) it has InnoDB type.

Following query takes long time to execute. How can I make it faster?

All comment_id, tag_id, status, datetime fields are indexed. I really have no idea how to optimize it further.

```
SELECT
    text
FROM comment
INNER JOIN tag_relation
    ON tag_relation.comment_id=comment.comment_id
WHERE tag_id='1022278'
AND status=1
ORDER BY comment.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Main cause of slowness is tag_relation table which has 1.5 million records. When it has less records execution time was faster.

Query plan:

[image]

Comment: where are the query plan? index?

Comment: prefix the query with explain and execute it, it will tell you which indexes it's using. Post the output in your question if it's not clear.

Comment: @almasshaikh  i updated my post with query plan.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson thanks i posted it above

Answer (score 3):

This is your query:

```
SELECT c.text
FROM comment c INNER JOIN
     tag_relation tr
     ON tr.comment_id = c.comment_id
WHERE t.tag_id = 1022278 AND c.status = 1
ORDER BY c.datetime DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

First, notice that I removed the single quotes from the value `1022278`.  If this is really a number, the single quotes can sometimes confuse SQL optimizers.  There are two ways to go about optimizing this query, depending on the selectivity of the various conditions.  The first is to have the indexes:

```
tag_relation(tag_id, comment_id)
comment(comment_id, status, datetime, text)
```

The second is a covering index for comments, and the most important part is the `comment_id` column.

The second is:

```
comment(status, comment_id, datetime)
tag_relation(comment_id, tag_id)
```

The basic issue is *which* table is scanned first for the `join`.  Using this index, the query would be processed as:

```
SELECT c.text
FROM comment c INNER JOIN
     tag_relation
WHERE c.status = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tag_relation tr
              WHERE tr.comment_id = c.comment_id AND tr.tag_id = 1022278 
             )
ORDER BY c.datetime DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

I'm not 100% sure that this avoids the file sort on the result set, but it might work.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try ASAP. Why indexing multiple fields at once is faster than indexing fields indivudially?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Why is it faster to create the indexes or why are composite indexes more useful for certain queries?

Comment: Why is using `index_name(comment_id, tag_id)` faster than `index_name2(comment_id)` and `index_name3(tag_id)`?

Comment: @user4220128 . . . The MySQL documentation on multi-column indexes is actually a good place to start understanding them:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right you have one index for tag_id and another index for comment_id. Try creating an composite index like:

```
create index ... on tag_relation(tag_id, comment_id)
```

This will make the index with tag_id redundant so it can be dropped.

AFAIK MySQL cannot do index anding, but even if it could a composite index would be more efficient.

Comment: sorry Lennart, this is the wrong way to go. Those indices are working fine as you can see in the "explain" and since comment_id is being used independently it cannot help to put it inside an index that starts with tag_id.

Comment: What do you mean by independently? Any decent optimizer will recognize that `where tag_id='1022278'` can be moved to the on clause.

Comment: because of the join clause tag_relation.comment_id=comment.comment_id. The criteria tag_id='1022278' can benefit from both single or the composite index, but for the join clause it would be much worse.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, are you suggesting that for `on tag_relation.comment_id=comment.comment_id and tag_id='1022278'` the performance will be much worse for an index like `(tag_id,comment_id)` than an index like `(tag_id)`?

Comment: yes, the index (tag_id,comment_id) is useless if your query just needs an index for comment_id.

Comment: my appologies, you are right! the optimizer can indeed search first on tag_id and then on comment_id. I guess I was not paying enough attention, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the "status" field. Although it is indexed, the index is not being used. It says "using where" for that table. You can force the use of the index for status but I'm not sure it will be useful, depending on selectivity, i.e., how many different values can "status" take. Alternatively, the documentation says that if "status" allows for NULL then you'll see the "using where". Does it allow for NULLs? If so, consider restricting it.

I just noticed that I overlooked the "ORDER BY", comment.datetime will need an index.

If you already have an index, then try a subquery:

```
SELECT     text
FROM       tag_relation
INNER JOIN (SELECT c.comment_id, c.text, c.datetime
            FROM comment c
            WHERE c.status = 1) comment
        ON tag_relation.comment_id = comment.comment_id
WHERE tag_id='1022278'
ORDER BY comment.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: Thank you! It does not allow for NULL. It is int(1) and only takes two values:0 and 1. 

Maybe I put 'status=1' in a wrong place? I'm not so sure